# Typescript nullable keys in object array type declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nullable, typing

I'm using Typescript to write React Components.
Currently I'm defining the types of props as Typescript `type`.
Here's an example:

```
type Props = {
  id: number //required
  name: string | null //optional
}

type ParentProps = Array<Props>

let props:ParentProps = [
  {
      id:5,
      name:"new"
  },
  {
      id:7,
  }
]

//Gives error: Property 'name' is missing in type '{ id: number; }' but required in type 'Props'
```

In this case I would like for the `type` `ParentProps`  to be just an array of the `type` `Props`. In practice, the nullable name key works well for individual objects of type `Prop`. When declaring an object of type `ParentProps` this it gives shown in the snippet above.

For consistency with simpler components I would rather keep using `type` to define component props, rather than interface. Would anyone have any advice on how to get declare a type to define an array of types objects that allow for certain null keys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about define `Props` in following ways:

```js
type Props = {
  id: number
  name?: string | null
}
```

or just

```js
type Props = {
  id: number
  name?: string
}
```

Also, if you want to leave `Props` definition unchanged, you can change `type ParentProps`:

```
type ParentProps = Array< Omit<Props, "name"> & { name?: string|null } >
```

Comment: This goes in the right direction, optional properties are indeed written with a `?`, but `null` should be removed from the type in this case. An optional property will never evaluate to `null` unless it was explicitly set to `null`, in which case the optionality of the property isn't relevant since it was specified. In other words, your second version is proper.